# Rewrite old php url with $arg_lang to new file in lang folder

Tags: nginx

I want to redirekt old php urls to new files in folders.

e.g. form newsboard.php?lang=en to /en/billboard

I tried:

```
if ($arg_lang = 'en') {
    rewrite ^/newsboard.php /en/billboard permanent;
}
```

It almost works as I am redirected to http://mydomian.com/en/billboard?lang=en but I don't want the ?lang=en at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a '?'

This works:

```
if ($arg_lang = 'en') {
    rewrite ^/newsboard.php /en/billboard? permanent;
}
```